Where is it exactly imply in Scriptures that 'DIAMOND' can be related to the believer in Christ?
We as Believers in Christ are supposed to reflect the diamond in us. If there is no factual means for our state to beam, let us know that Jesus says, "We are the light of the earth, a city set on the hill top that cannot be hidden." We are meant to be under and run dimmed to shine. 1 Corinthians 15:42 sates, "One star differs from another star..." which implies light. Diamond creates standards amongst precious stones.

What exactly is the question?

You won't find it in scripture. You could potentially get it from Ezekiel 28:13, but there it is just saying that the King of Tyre (being equated to Adam - some who are ignorant argue it is a fallen angel known as 'lucifer') was clothed in precious stones, but he himself was not the precious stone.
When it comes to just mentioning 'precious stones', there are quite a few passages, but you won't find any that state YOU are a diamond. Such as Revelation 21:11 & 18-21, it says the New Jerusalem will be adorned with precious stones (once again, as ornaments and clothing not people). Additionally, 1 Peter 1:7 says your faith is better than gold - but this is also not YOU as a believer, this is your trust in G-d that is better than gold.
